# Building multiple CPP files with mpic++ fails

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, mpi

I'm a newbie in using MPI, and I want to run my cpp project with mpi. I have a main cpp file which includes the main mpi stuff, and two other cpp files that are needed (and being called) in the main one.

In Ubuntu, I am doing:

`mpic++ -o mainFile.cpp otherFile1.cpp otherFile2.cpp`

But I am getting this error:

`` /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

I have mpic++ installed and I can run some other (one cpp file and very simple) projects, but not this one.
Could you please help?

Comment: you overwrote `mainFile.cpp` ! recreate it and try `mpic++ -o exe mainFile.cpp otherFile1.cpp otherFile2.cpp`

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, everyone need an extra pair of eyes once in a while! Feel free to delete the question since it will unlikely help future readers.